# How to select values of a list based on another list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list that has values

```
c("December 2022","November 2022")
```

I have another list that has

```
c("December 2022/File1.xlsx","December 2022/File2.xlsx","October 2022/File1.xlsx",
"October 2022/File2.xlsx","November 2022/File1.xlsx","November 2022/File2.xlsx")
```

I want to pull from second list only the ones that start with the values in the first list. My final list should include

```
c("December 2022/File1.xlsx","December 2022/File2.xlsx","November 
2022/File1.xlsx","November 2022/File2.xlsx")
```

My final list should not include those October 2022 files because it was not included in the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` by `paste`ing the values in the first vector (`v1`) as a single pattern to match and subset the values from the main vector 'v2'

```
grep(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), v2, value = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "December 2022/File1.xlsx" "December 2022/File2.xlsx" 
[3] "November 2022/File1.xlsx" "November 2022/File2.xlsx"
```

---

Or remove the substring suffix from second vector, create a logical vector with `%in%` to subset the 'v2'

```
v2[trimws(v2, whitespace = "/.*") %in% v1]
```

-output

```
[1] "December 2022/File1.xlsx" "December 2022/File2.xlsx"
[3] "November 2022/File1.xlsx" "November 2022/File2.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could `Vectorize` `grepl` and use it in `outer`.

```
l2[colSums(outer(l1, l2, Vectorize(grepl))) > 0]
# [1] "December 2022/File1.xlsx" "December 2022/File2.xlsx"
# [3] "November 2022/File1.xlsx" "November 2022/File2.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using "anonymous" `Vectorize` with `grep`

```
as.vector(Vectorize(\(x) grep(x, list1, value=T))(val))
[1] "December 2022/File1.xlsx" "December 2022/File2.xlsx"
[3] "November 2022/File1.xlsx" "November 2022/File2.xlsx"
```

which is close to `sapply` and `grep`

```
as.vector(sapply(val, grep, list1, value=T))
[1] "December 2022/File1.xlsx" "December 2022/File2.xlsx"
[3] "November 2022/File1.xlsx" "November 2022/File2.xlsx"
```

##### Data

```
val <- c("December 2022","November 2022")
list1 <- c("December 2022/File1.xlsx","December 2022/File2.xlsx","October 2022/File1.xlsx",
"October 2022/File2.xlsx","November 2022/File1.xlsx","November 2022/File2.xlsx")
```